# How can you extract the inferred string literal types for a function signature?

Tags: typescript, enums, string-literals

I'm trying to understand what it looks like to move from Enums to string literals.

One hanging up point is functions which take advantage of those keys.

For example, if I use enums, I might have something like:

```
enum Role {
  Standard = "Standard",
  Admin = "Admin",
}

type Standard = {
  role: Role.Standard
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Admin = {
  role: Role.Admin
  name: string
  securityLevel: "Normal" | "Elevated" | "High"
}

type Employee = Admin | Standard
```

Then, I write a helper function that does something based solely on the role:

```
function doSomething(role: Role){ /*...*/ )
```

In this case, I will almost *surely* be pulling the role from employee, but notably, I'm only passing a string into the function.

Is it possible to do this with string literals? The best I can get is to pass in an object that *has* the role on it:

```
type Standard = {
  role: "Standard"
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Admin = {
  role: "Admin"
  name: string
  securityLevel: "Normal" | "Elevated" | "High"
}

type Employee = Admin | Standard

function doSomething(e: Pick<Employee, "role">){
  return e.role === "Admin"
}

doSomething({role: "Admin"}) // compiles
doSomething({role: "Executive"}) // doesn't compile
```

I'm looking for the way to write it as:

```
doSomething("Admin") // compiles
doSomething("Executive") // doesn't compile
```

Alternatively, if this is just not something that's ever needed ... I'd like to understand a bit better - I'm fairly confident I've used Enums as types in functions before.

**Update** A possible alternative would be to somehow extract the string literal and then use that in the definition of the types that make up `Employee`, e.g.,

```
type RoleStrings = "Standard" | "Admin"
type Standard = {
  role: /* what goes here to say it's the string "Standard" that's _tied_ to the type `RoleStrings`? */
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Admin = {
  role: /* what goes here to say it's the string "Admin" that's _tied_ to the type `RoleStrings`? */
  name: string
  securityLevel: "Normal" | "Elevated" | "High"
}
```

If I could do that, then this becomes trivial:

```
function doSomething(role: RoleStrings){/*...*/)
```

**Update 2**

I think I have a solution that I like:

```
type RoleStrings = Employee['role']
function doSomething(role: RoleStrings){/*...*/}
```

This accomplishes my goal of deriving the allowable strings and ensuring that the for the function is as direct as possible without requiring an `Employee` (even if it's a `Pick`) object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`keyof typeof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#enums-at-compile-time) to get the type that represents the union of keys:

```
function doSomething(role: keyof typeof Role){ /*...*/ }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBASg9gG2FA3gKClAygFwIYgAmeAToVALxQBEuBxZ1ANBlAIKEQCWIlNH3EMzQBfNGgBmYEAGMcXOL0JwscCMBwALHgHMAFCUTAAXFADWwAJ5wJUHJYAOwG7CMBKFFAD0AKgB0AT5eUGJoyqrqWrp61AI81G7ewTJqDlxIAM5hKmoa2iD61ACiAB7AMmDyAG7ACUlQysAZIADkOFApEGlIaEA)

If you don't want to use `enum` at all, then you can just use a union:

```
function doSomething(role: "Standard" | "Admin"){ /*...*/ }
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEzgZTgWwKZQBYxgDmAFAE5wA22AXIgERpQCGYyzZy9iAPgwILJMhegEoA3ogD0AKgB0CmVMQBfAFBrUGHPkKl6g4WDHTlELAAcY1AM6b0WXAWIl6AUQAe2CCFgA3bBMpZVRsGzAAcihEc0wrajUgA)

Comment: Agreed that that works _if_ I use the `enum` approach, but I'm actually trying to _not_ do that. Notice that in my second example, there's no `Role` enum.

Comment: In that case, you can just use a union of string literals: `"Standard" | "Admin"`

Comment: Got it - that's what I was afraid of. That would mean I'd need to repeat myself and potentially get the types out of sync.

Answer (score 0):

Given:

```
type Standard = {
  role: "Standard"
  name: string
  age: number
}

type Admin = {
  role: "Admin"
  name: string
  securityLevel: "Normal" | "Elevated" | "High"
}

type Employee = Admin | Standard
```

The cleanest answer I've found is:

```
type RoleStrings = Employee['role']
function doSomething(role: RoleStrings){/*...*/}
```